# When Requesting Files should the user be inside the "Who can share outside your organization"

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-sharing, sharepoint-admin-center

Inside SharePoint admin center, we define that only users inside a security group can share with external users, as follow:-
[image]

this setting has affected SharePoint and ondrive sites. but does the above setting also apply to File Request feature? so a user can not request a file inside his/her onedrive site unless the user is inside the "who can share outside your organization"?

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, the settings have no effect on File Request feature. The user can request a file inside his/her onedrive site and the user don't need to inside the "who can share outside your organization".